# php strip_tags not working within a ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary, strip-tags

I have this line

```
$file = ($striptags != 1) ? $file : strip_tags($file, '<a>');
```

but this gives a syntax error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''<a>''
```

I don't understand why - can strip_tags not be used with the ternary operator? Thanks

Comment: I try you code, it works without errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)